# Java Keybinding Plus Key

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I was trying to create shortcuts for zooming in and out in an image editing application I'm creating and I noticed something strange. To bind the combination of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, I had to use the <kbd>=</kbd> key and a control and shift mask:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK + KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),"ZoomIn");
```

Neither of the combinations where I tried to directly bind to `VK_PLUS` worked:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK + KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),"ZoomIn");

getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),"ZoomIn");
```

It works right now with the very first line of code, but I was wondering why neither of the bottom two work and if this could (theoretically) be a problem if a keyboard did not have the <kbd>+</kbd> key as the shifted <kbd>=</kbd> key.

Comment: You apparently don't understand how the modifiers are used.  You second example is almost right, but the second parameter is `a bitwise-ored combination of any modifiers` (from the JavaDocs) not a sum of

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I forgot that I should use bitwise-or instead of addition, but that's not the problem.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is you seem to be thinking that the `KeyEvent.VK_PLUS` represents the `+` symbol above the `=` symbol.  I THINK that the `KeyEvent.VK_PLUS` actually represents the `+` key on the numpad instead.  What you could do is use both the `KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS` with the `shift`+`ctrl` modifiers and `KeyEvent.VK_PLUS` with the `ctrl` modifier

Comment: I stand corrected, the numpad `+` is `VK_ADD`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For numeric keypad plus try `KeyEvent.VK_ADD`:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD,
                KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "plus");
```

For plus on main keyboard (US keyboard layout) use:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),"plus");
```

For non US keyboard use `VK_PLUS`. See bugs [4262044](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4262044) and [6942481](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6942481) for some clarifications.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to agree with my testing!

Comment: @scaevity you're welcome! :) There seem to be some confusion around `VK_PLUS`. Looks like it is used on the keyboards where `+` is on the primary layer, whereas on US keyboard it is on secondary layer.

Comment: In the same way, for `ctrl -` you have `KeyEvent.VK_MINUS` and `KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT` (numpad).

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, the `VK_ADD` is actually used for the numpad <kbd>+</kbd>.

In order to use the <kbd>+</kbd> that appears along the top of the keybaord (next to the line of numbers), you would need to phsycially type <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

In this case, you need to use the `KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS` with a `KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` modifier.

But you also want the `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK` modifier as well.

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), "Test1");
```

The problem you're having is that the modifiers are `a bitwise-ored combination of any modifiers`

Comment: Hm... VK_ADD seems to be the numeric keyboard, but I can't get either the number pad or normal keyboard to work with VK_PLUS.

Comment: @scaevity Yes, you are right `VK_ADD` is for the numpad.  I can't find any use of the `VK_PLUS`, it might be used for different keyboard layouts.  The example code I used above works fine for me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1, it is amazing that there is nothing about this in spec.

Comment: @Aqua Yeah, it's what freaked me out when testing the code :P

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem today: I wanted to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>, which we press thinking of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, and associate it to a zoom in action. I use a Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard. While typing, to obtain the plus character, I need to use the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>, so I can't catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> directly. I could do like @Aqua suggested, which is to actually catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>, but it does not seem natural to me. I decided to see how some applications solve that problem.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) associates zoom in and zoom out to the numpad's plus and minus, respectively. That's an easy solution to the problem, but it was also not what I wanted. [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/), by its turn, does exactly what I want: it says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> is the key combination for zooming in, but what it actually catches is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>. Additionally, it also understands if I use the numpad's plus to zoom in.

### How I solved the problem

So, that's how I decided to solve the problem: while creating the `Action`, I associated the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to the action of zooming in, which actually can't be caught:

```
Action zoomInAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        zoomIn();
    }
};

zoomInAction.putValue(AbstractAction.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

JMenuItem zoomInMenuItem = new JMenuItem(zoomInAction);
viewMenu.add(zoomInMenuItem);
```

The ace in the hole is to catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> combination apart and treat it the same:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.isControlDown() && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS)) {
            zoomIn();
        }
    }
});
```

That way, the interface (i.e. the `JMenuItem` that corresponds to the `Action`) tells the user to use the key shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in. The user then presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>, thinking of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, but the application understands that combination and acts as the user expects it to do so.

This is my first Stack Overflow answer, so sorry for anything :)