# KeyStroke in InputMap for CTRL only must have CTRL_DOWN_MASK and CTRL_MASK (win10 only)

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, awt, keyboard-events

I have a custom component (inherited from `JComponent`) and like to underline a link while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed right like eclipse does. I decide to use `InputMap` and `ActionMap` for keypress/release feature.

I use this code to find the stroke:

```
stroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed CONTROL");
```

But it is wrong somehow. I debugged the `processKeyBinding` method of JComponent and find out that if i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> a `KeyStroke` having modifier 130.

[image]

(**this** is my InputMap, **arg0** is the incomming KeyStroke from the Keyboard)

I think 130 is the result of the addition of `CTRL_DOWN_MASK` who has code `128` and `CTRL_MASK` has code `2`.

1. Why do i have to add theese modifiers?
2. Is this cross-platform?
3. Is there any official documentation?

Full example camickr requests:

```
public class Test extends JLabel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test");
        final Test label = new Test();
        jf.getContentPane().add(label);
        jf.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 500);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        label.grabFocus();
    }

    public Test() {
        super("Foobar");
        addBoldOnCtrl();
    }

    public void addBoldOnCtrl() {
        final KeyStroke onDown = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK + KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        final String onDownName = "react on ctrl";
        getInputMap().put(onDown, onDownName);
        getActionMap().put(onDownName, new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final Font f = getFont();
                setFont(new Font(f.getFontName(), f.getStyle(), f.getSize() + 2));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#CTRL_MASK) - *"The Control key modifier constant. It is recommended that CTRL_DOWN_MASK be used instead.
"* - The reasoning would be that some part of the API was changed, probably to overcome a bug, and switched to preferring to use `CTRL_MASK_DOWN` generally

Comment: Do you mean you want to highlight a link using the mouse when the control key is down?  For that you can inspect the properties of the `MouseEvent`

Comment: @MadProgammer 1. InputMap does not work this way, InputMap uses the equals-method of the `AWTKeyStroke`. 2. No, lets assume i move the mouse over the link and without a mousemove i press CTRL the press of the key on the keyboard is not a mouse-move and no `MouseEvent` will be triggered.

Comment: I'm sorry, what (do you mean by your first point?!). I think if you take a look at [`KeyStroke#getKeyStroke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-int-int-) you will see that you can pass a modifier to it, the docs say that `x_DOWN_MASK` is preferred over the older `x_MASK`

Comment: As to your second point, I still think a `MouseMotionListener` is a preferred solution, as the `MouseEvent` provides a `modifier` parameter telling you which keys are down (shift/alt/ctrl), but that's me

Comment: @MadProgrammer To the second point: As i told you before, a keyboard-event is not a mouse-event!

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, all I'm saying is the `MouseEvent` has a nice [`isControlDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown()) (and others) mwthos which would suit. Mind you, I've never been able to get `VK_CONTROL` to work as a key binding, so that might explain why I'd prefer to use a `MouseMoitionListener`, but if that's not what you want, that's your choice and we can just leave it at that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, to listen only on the VK_CONTROL using some kind of KeyListener is not possible, you need to use `InputMap` and `ActionMap` because CTRL is some kind of a special key.

Comment: I tried camickr's solution and it works for me

Comment: Very interresting, looks like it is not cross-platform compatible and maybe a bug. What OS do you use?

Comment: I was using MacOS 10.11.4 and Java 8

Comment: Does `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK + KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);` works for you too?

Comment: No, it won't, the modifers need to be `|`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605109/java-keybinding-plus-key/15605266#15605266), but will test them or'd together

Comment: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)` and `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)` both seem to work

Comment: Without `CTRL_DOWN_MASK` win10 does not work. I will report a bug. As long as the bug is not fixed i use `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK` because it works on win10 and mac. Does the font grow frequently on the complete code (SSCCE) i posted in the question?

Comment: Font grow on what? That could be Windows 10 "feature"

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Why do i have to add theese modifiers?

You don't have to add both modifiers, just the CTRL_DOWN_MASK.

So to create the KeyStroke you can use:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control CONTROL");

KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
```

I don't know of any documentation that explicitly states you need to do this but the "modifier keys" are different than other keys on the keyboard.

Comment: No, they can not work without modifier `130`! See `AWTKeyStroke#equals`, its called by `InputMap.get()`.

Comment: I don't work with magic numbers. 130 means nothing to me. The above KeyStrokes work for me. That is the Action I add to the ActionMap is invoked when I press the CTRL key. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I would never have thought to combine `VK_CONTROL` with `CTRL_DOWN_MASK`, nice

Comment: See the edit above and if you still teling me you can drop the `KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK` please post your os/jdk, mine is win10/1.8.0_31.

Comment: BTW: Using "control CONTROL" and holding Ctrl let frequently grows the font, this is not what i want.

Comment: @PeterRader,  Whats with the downvote? everything I stated in the answer is accurate. `you can drop the KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK` - yes I can. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7. This is why a `SSCCE`  and OS/ JDK should be posted with every question so people can test to see if they have the same problems. `holding Ctrl let frequently grows the font,` - This is normal behaviour. holding down any key will generate multiple mousePressed events. Both KeyStrokes work this way for me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sometimes I don't know what my mind is thinking but I get lucky :)

Comment: @camickr The reason in your comment does not make sense, but you are upset and i remove the downvote. Dam, i can not remove the downvote until someone edit it.

Comment: @PeterRader, that fact that is doesn't work for you does not make the answer incorrect because it does in fact work for me. In fact you should actually be "accepting" the answer because my insistence for you to post your SSCCE ultimately lead to the conclusion that your problem is platform related so the question has been answered.

Comment: @camickr From my point of view: the first answer is wrong. The second question is answered by the comments. A "I do not know" for the 3rd question is low quality. Id like to remove the downvote because you are upset, but now you like me to accept a answer what in my eyes is wrong and has low quality?

Comment: @PeterRader It is NOT wrong. The single line of code you included did NOT work for me so I gave a simple answer that DID work for me (and it was confirmed by MadProgrammer). For you to continually state it was wrong when two people confirm it works is mindboggling. In addition you then down vote the answer because it doesn't work for you??? How does that encourage people to take the time to try and resolve your problems? Without my comments and suggestions your question would not be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get it. What single line of code do you mean? `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed CONTROL");`?

Comment: @PeterRader, Exactly in your original question that is all you posted. That did NOT work for me, so I corrected that single line of code with two suggestions that did work for me (and for MadProgrammer) assuming it would also work for you and you would not need to use the two masks. As it turns out you need the two masks because of a Windows bug. But you sure can't blame me for my attempt based on the information you presented in your original question.