# KeyBinds in Java break when holding shift

Tags: java

When I use my keybinds, they work just fine. But the minute I hold shift and try to use keybinds, my computer doesn't detect that keys are being pressed/changed. Also, when trying to detect if shift is being pressed/released, it seems like nothing happens.

```
package main;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Input 
{

    private InputMap im;
    private ActionMap am;

    public Input(JComponent component)
    {
        im = component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        am = component.getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ESCAPE"), "exitGame");
        am.put("exitGame", new AbstractAction()
                {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void createKey(String key, AbstractAction action)
    {
        String command = key + "Action";
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), command);
        am.put(command, action);
    }

    public void createKey(int key, boolean released, AbstractAction action)
    {
        String command = key + "Action";
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, released), command);
        am.put(command, action);
    }

}
```

```
public void keyInput(Input input)
    {
        input.createKey("A", new MoveAction(Direction.LEFT, false));
        input.createKey("released A", new MoveAction(Direction.LEFT, true));
        input.createKey("D", new MoveAction(Direction.RIGHT, false));
        input.createKey("released D", new MoveAction(Direction.RIGHT, true));

//Added this for testing purposes, but without it, holding shift down seems to stop all other inputs.
        input.createKey(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, false, new AbstractAction()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sprint = true;
                    System.out.println("Test!"); //THIS LINE NEVER APPEARS.
                }
            });
        input.createKey(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, true, new AbstractAction()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sprint = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

(The keyInput method is part of a seperate class.)

Comment: [Shift] is a "modifier", so it's a seperate binding

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right I've read this online, that's why i implemented a seperate createKey() method that takes an integer as a parameter (Apparently using KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT solves this) but even with this it doesn't work. Also I don't understand why holding it causes my other keys to stop taking input

Comment: Basically, you’re saying when “key A is pressed do something”, but, when you press A & shift together, you’re getting a different key stroke, which doesn’t meet what you’ve asked for

Comment: Remember, there is a difference between “a” and “A”, maybe have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605109/java-keybinding-plus-key/15605266?r=SearchResults#15605266

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key stroke is made up of a number of parts.  The key code which generated the event, zero or more modifiers, which can change the meaning of the key code, and if it was pressed or released.

A individual key stroke could have different meaning based on the modifiers, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd> will change <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>!</kbd>.

This makes <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> different from just <kbd>a</kbd>.  When you also consider that you have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Wnd</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> as well and they can be combined together, this gives every key a large number of additional possible meanings.

Key bindings are fun.  You can define a single action and apply it to multiple key stroke configurations

For example, we could start with...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

am.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        label.setText("left");
    }
});
am.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        label.setText("right");
    }
});
am.put("released", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        label.setText("---");
    }
});
```

This defines three actions which can be executed, `left`, `right`, `released`.  Each one simply changes the the text of `JLabel` to some state, but you get the idea.

Then you can apply these actions to multiple key strokes, for example...

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "left");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), "left");
```

So, pressing <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> will trigger the `left` action

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "right");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), "right");
```

Pressing <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will trigger the `right` action

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "released");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "released");

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "released");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "released");
```

and releasing any four of those keys will generate the `released` action

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("---");

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            am.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    label.setText("left");
                }
            });
            am.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    label.setText("right");
                }
            });
            am.put("released", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    label.setText("---");
                }
            });

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), "left");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "right");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), "right");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "released");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "released");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Now I can work around it :)